# How to broadcast a Bitcoin Gold transaction

Tags: transactions, api, bitcoin-gold

I'd like to broadcast a signed BTG transaction - In Bitcoin it's very easy to do with tools like [coinb.in](http://coinb.in). Is there a public RPC/API endpoint similar to the following examples where you can broadcast a signed transaction:

- coinb.in
- chain.so
- block.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin Gold is a fork of Bitcoin. You can just start up a Bitcoin Gold node and broadcast transactions using `sendrawtransaction`. 
Another option is to use an `insight-api`.

https://btgexplorer.com/ is a fork of the famous insight block explorer. You can use their API to broadcast your raw transaction using these docs:
https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api#transaction-broadcasting

Send a POST request to https://btgexplorer.com/api/tx/send with `rawtx` as a parameter.